# UI Bootstrap typeahead value to be used by other typeahead objects

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a ui-bootstrap type-ahead that pulls the states from a JSON doc. It works. What I need is to take that selected value and use it in another objects to retrieve data based on that selection. When I call the $scope value of the input field with the type-ahead function the value isn't being pass? I guess,but when I use it as a drop-down select it works. What am I missing here?

State Type-ahead:

```
<input type=text ng-model="selectedState"typeahead="state.value for state in states | fileter: $viewValue | limitTo:3" ng-change="updateState()" placeholder="Enter State"/>
```

or 
State Drop-down select:

```
<select ng-options="state.value for state in states" ng-model="selectedState" ng-change="updateState()"></select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.updateState = function(){
  $scope.wCenters = wCenterFactory.get({state:$scope.selectedState.value});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try typeahead-on-select instead of ng-change?  I think that passes the selected item in.